# How do you determine the coordinates of a point on a vector if you are given one point?

Tags: vectors

> Vector AB - the tail is at (-4,2) and the head is at (-1,3). Determine the coordinates of point D on vector CD, if C(-6,0) and vector CD = vector AB.

---

I tried to find the slope of vector CD knowing that it is the same as vector AB.

Determining the slope of vector AB:

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (3-2)/((-1)-(-4)) = 1/3

Setting the slope of vector AB to the slope of vector CD:

1/3 = (y2-0)/(x2-(-6))

I stopped here because I realized that I cannot do anything if I do not know x or y.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Work with $x$ and $y$ components of vectors. you already know $\vec {AB}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $A = (-4,2), B = (-1,3), C = (-6,0), D = (x,y)$. Thus $\vec{AB} = \vec{CD}\implies <-1 - (-4), 3 - 2> = <x - (-6), y - 0>\implies x+6=3, y = 1\implies x = -3,y=1$. So $D = (-3,1)$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Think of $A,B,C,D$ as position vectors in plane. So $A=(-4,2)$ etc.

Vector $AB=B-A$, where $B$ is head, $A$ is its tail. Similarly $CD=D-C$.

Problem is asking for $AB=CD \Rightarrow D=B-A+C$ from above.